# Firebase query (in swift) to determine if username already exists in database

Tags: ios, swift, search, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have very little experience with Firebase and iOS and was wondering if it was possible to create a query in Swift to find specific data in the Firebase's JSON structure.

When a user creates an account in the app, he is prompted to chose a username. When the user presses on the "Continue" button on this same screen, I would like to query the DB in real-time to determine if the username the user chose already exists or not.

I read a bunch of articles on the web but couldn't find anything that would let me achieve my goal. So far, I wrote the following code which doesn't work, but I am unable to pinpoint the source of the problem (note that username.text is the textfield where the user enters his desired username and with which the verification is made) :

```
FIRDatabase
    .database()
    .reference()
    .child("username")
    .queryOrderedByValue()
    .queryEqual(toValue: self.username.text!)
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in

            if snap.exists(){
                // Username unavailable, choose another one
            } else {
                // Username available, OK to keep this username
            }
})
```

The DB structure is as follows :

```
{
  "users" : {

      USER_1_UID : {
          "account" : {
              "email" : "test@stackoverflow.com",
              "first name" : "myFirstName",
              "last name" : "myLastName",
              "username" : "my.username"
          }
      }

      USER_2_UID : {
          "account" : {
              "email" : "test@stackoverflow.com",
              "first name" : "myFirstName2",
              "last name" : "myLastName2",
              "username" : "my.username2"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I am open to change my DB structure to add the "usernames" note as shown below which will contain all of the usernames registered if it can make the querying easier :

```
{
  "users" : {

      USER_1_UID : {
          "account" : {
              "email" : "test@stackoverflow.com",
              "first name" : "myFirstName",
              "last name" : "myLastName",
              "username" : "my.username"
          }
      }

      USER_2_UID : {
          "account" : {
              "email" : "test@stackoverflow.com",
              "first name" : "myFirstName2",
              "last name" : "myLastName2",
              "username" : "my.username2"
          }
      }
  }

  "listOfUsernames" : {
      USER_1_UID : "my.username"
      USER_2_UID : "my.username2"
  }
}
```

Any help at this point will be welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is pretty close. Three changes:

```
Remove queryOrderedByValue
```

then, you've buried your user information too deep

```
  USER_1_UID : {
      "account" : {
          "email" : "test@stackoverflow.com",
          "first name" : "myFirstName",
          "last name" : "myLastName",
          "username" : "my.username"
      }
  }
```

Change to (remove the account node name as it's not needed)

```
  USER_1_UID : {
    "email" : "test@stackoverflow.com",
    "first name" : "myFirstName",
    "last name" : "myLastName",
    "username" : "my.username"
  }
```

and then you need to tell Firebase which node you are querying

so change to

```
let usersRef = rootRef.child("users")
let queryRef = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "username")
                            .queryEqual(toValue: "some user name")
queryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
  print(snapshot) //you need snapshot, or snap or some other var name
})
```

Lastly, you don't need a listOfUsernames node, your users node will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Jay. However it doesn't work on my end. The code in the closure doesn't get executed (I tested this by putting a simple **print("The program got this far")** after the **{ snapshot in** but nothing is ever printed in the console). Is this Firebase query ok to use even though the key I am trying to access is nested under _users/**someUniqueUID**/account/username_ ? Thanks

Comment: @ayarem502 lol. You are correct! See my slightly updated answer as it will take care of the problem. I overlooked the extra node name within each user node which is unneeded.

Comment: I had the "account" node as I also have a "profile" node with different type of information in it that I haven't included in my current post to avoid confusion. However, I tried removing the "account" node and executing the code and it still doesn't enter the closure. I then tried to print the query to see what it's comparing the username to : **print(FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username"))** This returns something that I honestly don't really understand : **(/users {
    i = username;
})** .But shouldn't I expect a list of usernames? Thanks again

Comment: @ayarem502 I duplicated my suggested structure and ran it with the code in my answer and when run, it returns the user - so the code works. In your comment, you have .quer‌​yOrdered(byChild: "username")), but you also need .queryEqual(toValue: "some username") to return users that match the query. And no, it will not return usernames; it will return all nodes that contain that username. Also, there's no need for an account node and a profile node for a user. [Denormalize](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) the data in this use case.

Comment: Just to make sure on my end I have the following : **FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: self.username.text).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in** ... Is this equivalent to your code? (I tried keeping it on one line)

Comment: @ayarem502 That looks pretty close - as long as *users* is a child of your root node and the Firebase structure is as I posted in my answer. Also remember that Firebase is case sensitive so the user names would have match exactly. Also - when doing a query, it may return multiple nodes (probably not in this case as the usernames seem to be discreet) so you need to iterate over them to pull out each child snapshot.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of my code and structure. As you can see, on line 33 I placed a breakpoint on the printing. This breakpoint never gets reached and nothing gets printed in the console. Do you see a problem with my code? (I hard-coded the username to search for test purposes) : https://s23.postimg.org/83zq0bwzf/Untitled_1.jpg

Comment: @ayarem502 I do. As I mentioned in my answer and comments, *"as long as users is a child of your root node"* which it isn't. Users is a child of the lunchtime- node... unless that's your root node? And the code is incorrect as well: you need snapshot (a variable) not FIRDataSnapshot. Make your query look like the one in the answer and it will work (just tested it)

Comment: The lunchtime-XXXX node is the root node. It cannot be erased. Don't you have this node at the root of your Firebase DB when you test your code? The "users" node is right below the "lunchtime-XXXX" node which should make it work. Just tested the code by replacing "FIRDataSnapshot" by "snapshot" but still no luck : **FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: "remy2").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in print(snapshot.value) })**

Comment: Something is not working on my end... I tried copying your answer directly in my code and still nothing appears : **let usersRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")
                let queryRef = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "username")
                    .queryEqual(toValue: "remy2")
                queryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                    print(snapshot) //you need snapshot, or snap or some other var name
                })**

Comment: @ayarem502 I copied and pasted your code into my project and it worked. Keep in mind that I used the Firebase structure in my answer. You may want to check your rules to ensure you are allowed read/write access to that node.